# MIDlet audio playback noise

Tags: java, audio, java-me, symbian

I'm having this terrible +/- 1-second noise in 1-second intervals during my MIDlet wav playback.

```
Player p = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio.wav"), "audio/x-wav");
p.start();
```

Adding prefetch or realize doesn't change a thing. Any idea what can it be?

The interface is extending GameCanvas, implementing Runnable. Could it be a reason?

Comment: let me confirm your question, your player plays noise after playing `audio.wav` is it what you asking for ?

Comment: Well, yeah. I can hear parts of the original audio.wav interrupted by some noise in regular intervals..

Comment: it seems the problem with your device, have you tried with emulator and changing the wav file ? when next time you comment apply @org.life.java so that i will get notified

Comment: @org.life.java thx for hint, I tried other wav file that didn't even play. no null input error, just silence. i tried this on emulator, will try today on device when i get one.

Comment: ok it works well there must be some other issue, I doubt in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator issue... if you have this audio problem test your midlet on actual device.